# Is this construction of Bochner integral problematic?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definition, banach-spaces

I'm reading the construction of Bochner integral from this Wikipedia [page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral).

> [image]

The construction seems circular and thus problematic to me. We are calculating an integral containing $f$, i.e. $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X}\left\| \color{blue}{f}-s_{n}\right\|_{B} \, d \mu=0$$ before we define the integral of $f$, i.e. $$\int_{X} f \, d \mu=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X} s_{n} \, d \mu$$

Could you please verify my observation? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the function $x\mapsto \|f-s_n\|_B$ is a function in $X\to\mathbb{R}$ or $X\to\mathbb{C}$ as opposed to the function $f$, which has values in some Banach space.

They are extending the integral of real or complex valued functions, to some functions that return values in a Banach space.